# Ms Access Sql combining multiple Tables of potential different values

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is a simplistic view of my tables and needs.
Table A.
Pickerid, Grade, Weight, Date

Table B.
Pickerid, Grade, Weight(set to zero)

Table B was defined to have all pickers from 1 to 50 along with every grade possible. PR, AP, AA, AM, CA, And a default value of 0 for each grade.
IE 
Picker1 PR 0
Picker1 AP 0
Picker1 AA 0 etc etc for all 50 pickers.

Note that in Table A. A picker will have many boxes per day with the same grades but with different box weights.
They will not necessary have all the grades possible so if a grade is not present then I need to have a 0 returned along side the grade.
I need to "Sum" the weights per picker, per grade and if a grade is not present in Table A then the default is used from Table B.

This is in MS Access 2010 using Sql.

I have tried Inner, Outer joins, unions, but can not get the result needed.

Apprciate your expertice

Comment: outer join with group by

Comment: I'd close as duplicate but this question makes up approximately five million of the ten million SO questions so which one to make it a duplicate of?